# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] Gmail when Threaded

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, ssl, gmail-api

I am able to get a list of emails containing a query in Python however when I run the code from within a thread I get the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]
```

here's how I'm calling the thread:

```
Thread(target=get_messages_for_label, args=({'recruitment'})).start()
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
response = service.users().labels().list(userId=user_id).execute()
```

However when I run it without a thread (as a simple method call) it works fine.

It's hard to share the code in between as there are quite a few method calls in between where the thread is started and the error occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found this article: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety.

According to the documentation the Gmail API is built on top of Httplib2 which is not thread safe.

As a work around you can supply a new instance of the http object to each commands execute method.

In my case

```
service.labels().list().execute()
```

Becomes:

```
service.users().labels().list(userId=user_id)\
   .execute(http=self.__get_credentials().authorize(httplib2.Http()))
```

Comment: What's the `self` object you're calling `__get_credentials()` on?

Comment: In my case, I had been passing the `service` object to the multithreaded part of the code (using concurrent futures) and getting this error. By instead passing the credentials and creating a new service in each thread it started working: `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)`

Comment: You just made my day even though the answer is 6 years old! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Google's `oauth2client` is now deprecated. When using the new google-auth library, you can create an authorized Http instance as follows:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import _auth

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(...)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
http = _auth.authorized_http(credentials)
service.files().get(...).execute(http=http)
```